# How kill / stop an app in background after a certain amount of time

Tags: ios, objective-c, background

I would like to know if it is possible to make an app auto-kill itself or just stop when it is in background, after a specific amount of time ?

My concern is about security, I would like the app to clear the memory after several hours.

Comment: Killing app is against Apple's guidelines.

Comment: Thanks, but what about stopping the app, and force it to restart for the next launch ?

Comment: For performing specific cleanups I think your best shot is to take advantage of the delegate methods in AppDelegate: applicationWillTerminate, applicationDidBecomeActive, applicationDidEnterBackground, etc. The killing or stopping of your app should be handled by the device directly.

Comment: @carlodurso I though about using applicationDidEnterBackground, but do you think I could put a NSTimer in it ? Or another solution was to take a timestamp in applicationDidEnterBackground, then in applicationDidBecomeActive restart the app if the time was too long.

Comment: Sounds like a smart way to handle it. How about `NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [endTime timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime];` saving timestamps in core data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of my projects I use this code snippet, probably you can tailor to your needs.

```
- (NSInteger)daysBetweenDate:(NSDate*)fromDateTime andDate:(NSDate*)toDateTime
{
    NSDate *fromDate;
    NSDate *toDate;

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay startDate:&fromDate
                 interval:NULL forDate:fromDateTime];
    [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay startDate:&toDate
                 interval:NULL forDate:toDateTime];

    NSDateComponents *difference = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                               fromDate:fromDate toDate:toDate options:0];

    return [difference day];
}
```

As I mentioned in my comment, you'd probably want to save timestamps in Core Data and when 'applicationDidBecomeActive` call the above method.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will do it mannualy like that if Apple doesn't give option to do that